# AndroidManifest.xml Required Permissions settings not saving in .NET MAUI application

Tags: c#, .net, android-manifest, maui, maui-community-toolkit

In the CommunityToolkit.Maui.Sample app found [here](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui.git) under "samples," the folder picker doesn't work on Android as it says it doesn't have permission. I'm trying to check the setting for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in the Required Permissions section of the `AndroidManifest.xml`, but there are some issues. If I check its box, leave the file, and then come back, it is suddenly unchecked. But in the source code for `AndroidManifest.xml`, that `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is present in code. Also, the title next to the checkbox in Required Permissions reads unlike the other titles. Instead of just saying `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` it says `<span color='red'>READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE</span>`.

I think this one permission will fix the folder picker on Android, but it keeps unchecking the setting. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: If you are having issues with authentication see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/authentication?tabs=android  For troubleshooting see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/troubleshooting#platform-version-isnt-present  The latest target version may not be present.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can check the [source code about the FolderPicker on the android](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/blob/1bb29e0a48a98245d85a3182f104358b7d731ad1/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core/Essentials/FolderPicker/FolderPickerImplementation.android.cs#L15). It used the  `Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>()`. But the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission has been removed since android 13.0. So it will always `throw new PermissionException("Storage permission is not granted.");` on the android api 33.

I have tested it on the android 12.0 and it worked well. And you can check the known issue about [[BUG] READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission on Android 13](https://github.com/CommunityToolk).